# Low resolution after installing Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, 18.04, sis-graphics

During the installation and with a liveCD, I have 1024x768 resolution.  After first boot it will only give me 640x480.

Old laptop with the dreaded SIS graphics chip.

Comment: I updated another partition on the same computer.  Kubuntu 14.04.  In the process grub updated and took control back from the xubuntu install.  NOW I get 1024x768.   I cannot explain it.  All is well now.  Go xubuntu team!!!

Answer (score 4):

After trying many other answers that just give a black screen I found a solution in [here](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/video-cards/sis-graphic-card-support-(771671-pcie-vga)/).

Just create a xorg.conf in /etc/X11/

```
sudo leafpad /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

with the following content

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Generic Video Card"
    VendorName  "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
        BoardName   "771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter"
    Busid "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver "vesa"
    Screen 0
        Option "UseFBDev" "true"
        Option "DPMS"
        Option "ShadowFB"
        Option "MaxXFBMem"
        VideoRam 262016
        Option "RenderAccel" "true"
        Option "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
        Option "backingstore" "true"
        Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"

EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    Vendorname    "Generic LCD Display"
    Modelname    "LCD Panel 1280x800"
    HorizSync 20-107
        VertRefresh 50-185
  modeline  "800x600@56" 36.0 800 824 896 1024 600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync
  modeline  "800x600@60" 40.0 800 840 968 1056 600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x768@60" 80.14 1280 1344 1480 1680 768 769 772 795 -hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x720@60" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync
  modeline  "1280x800@60" 83.46 1280 1344 1480 1680 800 801 804 828 -hsync +vsync
    Gamma    1.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    Defaultdepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Virtual    1280    768
        Modes        "1280x768@60"    "1280x720@60"    "800x600@60"    "1280x800@60"    "800x600@56"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load "dri"
    Load "dbe" # Double-Buffering Extension
    Load "v4l" # Video for Linux
    Load "extmod"
    Load "type1"
    Load "freetype"
    Load "glx" # 3D layer
    Load "GLcore"
    Load "i2c"
    Load "bitmap"
    Load "ddc"
    Load "int10"
    Load "vbe"
    Load "speedo"
    Load "record"
EndSection

Section "DRI"
        Mode 0666
EndSection
```